# Fastest way to read Large (>5GB) log files with inbuilt funcs and parallelization?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Being new to python I was tasked to find the fastest way to parse large log files in Python.

These are the methods I have tried so far and they give me between 33 to 43 seconds of processing time.
This one took the longest at 43 secs:

```
tflines1 = tfile.readlines()

time_data_count = 0
for line in tflines1:
    if 'TIME_DATA' in line :
        time_data_count += 1
if time_data_count > 20 :
    print("time_data complete")
else:
    print("incomplete time_data data")
```

This one took 34 secs on avg:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    time_data_count = 0
    while True:
        memcap = f.read(102400)
        memcaplist = memcap.split("\n")
        for line in memcaplist:
            if 'TIME_DATA' in line:
                time_data_count += 1
        if not memcap:
            break
```

This one averaged 36 seconds:

```
with open(filename, 'r', buffering=102400) as f:
    time_data_count = 0
    for line in f:
        if 'TIME_DATA' in line:
            time_data_count += 1
```

This one averaged 36 secs:

```
logfile = open(filename)
time_data_count = 0
for line in logfile:
    if 'TIME_DATA' in line:
            time_data_count += 1
```

The fastest was this one which did the task in 26.8 seconds And I don't know why it is the fastest. I don't get what makes it so special. With this one and others like it where I specified the bytes, I am worried that there might be a file or two where a line is split in between byte chunks and the string I am looking for gets split in half. This would result in an erroneous count. How would one address this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    time_data_count = 0
    while True:
        memcap = f.read(102400)
        time_data_count += memcap.count('TIME_DATA')
        if not memcap:
            break
    if time_data_count > 20:
        print("time_data complete")
    else:
        print("incomplete time_data data")
```

Anyways, the boss man told me to look into other ways that might make things faster. He suggested list comprehension and reading a file object as binary. I don't think list comprehension will help much and for being able to extract data I need from file.I feel like reading the file as binary would create extra lines of code and issues where the code needs to know when to anticipate certain character. Would even reading a file as binary make a difference? This isn't c++ where you can use pointers.

I briefly read up on parallelization but I am not sure if that would work for our use case. I need to track how many times certain strings show up so I am not sure how splitting a file into different threads would work when you want to keep track of a count of things. Is this even possible?

@TimPeters here is an edit of the final method using binary file and seek():

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    time_data_count = 0
    while True:

        memcap = f.read(102400)
        f.seek(-tdatlength, 1)
        time_data_count += memcap.count(b'TIME_DATA')

        if not memcap:
            break
    if time_data_count > 20:
        print("time_data complete")
    else:
        print("incomplete time_data data")
```

Another method I tried:

```
with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=102400) as f:
    time_data_count = 0
      #ask tenzin about seek in this situation
    for line in f:
        if b'TIME_DATA' in line:
            time_data_count += 1
    f.seek(-tdatlength, 2)
    if time_data_count > 20:
        print("time_data complete")
    else:
        print("incomplete time_data data")
    print(time_data_count)
```

Comment: What does the logfile look like? Might be beneficial if you can find a pattern in when/where `TIME_DATA` is found within the files.

Comment: @JayMody There is definitely a pattern. How would this help?

Comment: It depends on the format/pattern, but a simple example would be `TIME_DATA` only occurs on odd lines, well that would cut your search down in half. It's hard to say how it can help, it all depends on what the file actually looks like.

Comment: @JayMody I just checked and although there is a pattern, it is irregular because these log are from a factory and sometimes the data are incomplete depending on what sort of items are available. This makes predicting where it will occur (odd or even) tough. In fact that is the point of the test i am writing, to be able to catch when time_data is not complete. While the log files I have see so afar have a good count, I can see by searching through the files that the preceeding bodies before the time_data line are not the same length or end with the same characters.

Comment: @JayMody sadly, the material is senstive so I cannot share much of what the log looks like. A sample:
END_PROBE_DEFS

@ 1 1576874500 14TB:0TB

TIME_DATA {
TIME_INIT                        421.000
TIME_OPENS                        31.000
TIME_PTRES                        16.000
TIME_OPENS_HVMON0                 47.000
TIME_PTRES_HVMON0                 31.000
TIME_OPENS_HVMON1                 31.000
TIME_PTRES_HVMON1                 31.000
TIME_STEP                        624.000
}

Comment: A simple solution to increase speed would be to use the `multiprocessing` library to process multiple logs at the same time. For example, if you have 4 available cores, your code would process 4 files in the time of 1.

Comment: @JayMody Ah so in this case, the file itself is not being split across multiple cores? I'd assume splitting a file across multiple cores wouldn't work for the purpose i am after which is to count how many times "time_data" appears?

Comment: You could still thread it in such a way that the file is split up into multiple threads (with a common shared counter resource), but I would go with the easier option of just use multiithreading on a file on file basis.

Comment: Use binary files. You don't care about line ends at all. After each read, use `f.seek()` to move the file pointer back 8 bytes (`len("TIME_DATA") - 1`). Then you'll find the instances split across chunks. But note too that you're done then when the `.read()` returns <= 8 bytes.

Comment: Reading files in chunks like some of the snippets do will potentially miss some occurrences of the `'TIME_DATA'` string because it got split up between two of them — so it doesn't matter how fast it is. @Jay Mody's answer currently has the same problem.

Comment: @TimPeters What do you mean use binary files? YOu mean read the log file in binary using "rb+"? Also I do care about when the line ends because I want to make sure my file doesn't get chopped in bits in the middle of a line. I am new to Python and processing files in Python so I don't know what seek() is and I am not sure how that would work when one part of that line is in the previous chunk now pushed out of memory

Comment: If you run `grep -F -c string file` or `find /c string file` (depending on os), do you see any speedup? Trying to determine if CPU usage is the issue here or I/O. Grep and find are the lower bound for CPU usage.

Comment: Use "rb". "+" isn't needed unless you also want to write to the file. `seek()` is a bog-standard C thing Python exposes. Read the docs. Don't argue about it - try it. Understanding will come later :-)

Comment: if it's just text files, I'd probably just use `split -l {LINES} {FILENAME}` and process the individual chunks as @JayMody does.  https://www.linuxtechi.com/split-command-examples-for-linux-unix/

Comment: @monkut I am in a Windows environment

Comment: I strongly recommend WSL (windows subsystem for linux) which would allow you to use any/all linux commands freely ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could parse multiple log files in parallel using python's `multiprocessing` library:

```
import multiprocessing

def process_log(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        time_data_count = 0
        while True:
            memcap = f.read(102400)
            time_data_count += memcap.count('TIME_DATA')
            if not memcap:
                break
        if time_data_count > 20:
            print("time_data complete")
            return True
        else:
            print("incomplete time_data data")
            return False

filepaths = # load all the filepaths here with something like glob.glob("path/to/logdir/*.log)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_cores_to_use) # set num cores to use

number_of_complete_logs = 0
for complete in pool.imap_unordered(process_log, filepaths):
    if complete:
        number_of_complete_logs += 1

print(number_of_complete_logs)
```

This way, if you have 4 cores, you would process 4 log files in the time of 1. Plus, each file is worked on separately, so the `TIME_DATA` counter stays intact.

If you're processing a lot of logfiles, I recommend using [`tqdm`](https://www.google.com/search?q=tqdm&oq=tqdm&aqs=chrome..69i57l2j69i59l2j69i60l4.390j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
for complete in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(process_log, filepaths), total=len(filepaths)):
```

This way you can track the progress and estimate how long the entire operation will take.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215293/discussion-on-answer-by-jay-mody-fastest-way-to-read-large-5gb-log-files-with).

Answer (score 1):

Here's using [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) to improve I/O performance. I can't benchmark it without your log files, but I believe it will be a lot faster than line-based I/O.

If you wish to parallelize it, you could expand on this as the mmap object supports random access (see `seek()`). So you could spin up multiple threads starting the search from several points in the file at the same time.

```
import mmap
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
    target = b'TIME_DATA'
    tl = len(target)
    idx = -tl
    counter = 0
    while True:
        idx = mm.find(target, idx + tl)
        if idx < 0:
            break
        counter += 1
    print(counter)
    mm.close()
```

Comment: interesting but look at the first post on this quora: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-fastest-ways-to-read-text-lines-in-large-files-by-Python

He says "Bear in mind this is a high-level programming spell and needs to be used carefully. The mapped-in file is exactly as it appears on disk. It's up to you to deal with line endings (different on Windows than Linux and Mac), Unicode character encoding, etc. You also have to be careful about making strings from this mapped-in memory because it is all to easy to cause your memory usage to explode."  

Thoughts? @jingx

Comment: The sample code in my answer deals with files in binary mode, so there are no line ending issues. Since your target string is entirely ASCII, you won't have problems with  encoding either even if your log file actually contains UTF-8 characters beyond ASCII.

Comment: So because we are dealing with binary, we won't worry abotu encoding format and new lines then? What about eating up too much memory like he warns? @jingx

Comment: Why don't you just try it? It's not like you have to write a lot of code.

Comment: I intend to. My brain is a bit fried after 12 hours of work so I wanted to ask ahead of time before implementing it tomorrow morning. I figured get as much advice while I still got you online :D

Comment: i tried it and it is faster than all but one of the methods I used. THe last one. this mmap method as you wrote it takes 12 secs. The last method in my OP does it in 5 secs with the seek method(). I think I can use your mmap example for multiple scenarious. The question is, does this method as you wrote run the risk of cutting my log files into chunks? If so where does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: As long as you only open the log files in read-only mode, you don't need to worry about them being modified.

Answer (score 1):

Hints aren't working here, so fleshing out the check-for-overlaps idea in a concrete way equivalent to - but not using - `.seek()`.

```
target = b"TIME_DATA"
windowsize = len(target) - 1
last = b""
target_count = 0
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        memcap = f.read(102400)
        if not memcap:
            break
        overlap = last[-windowsize :] + memcap[: windowsize]
        if target in overlap:
            target_count += 1
        target_count += memcap.count(target)
        last = memcap
```

`windowsize` is one too small for `target` to match in the portion of `overlap` taken from `last`, or the one from `memcap`, so if `target` is found in `overlap` it must match at least one character in each of the pieces: it really is an overlapping match. In the other direction, if there is match across adjacent chunks, it must start at one of the last `windowsize` characters of `last` and end at one of the first `windowsize` characters of `memcap`, so `windowsize` is big enough to find any such match.

EDIT: repaired a too-strong claim below.

There's one area of ambiguity:  if some prefix of `target` is also a suffix of `target`, matches can overlap.  For example, "abab" has "ab" as both a prefix and a suffix. So if one chunk ends with, and the next chunk starts with, "abab", `overlap` will be "bababa". Do you, or do you not, want to count the "abab" in the middle of that?  That is, does "abab" occur 2 or 3 times in "abababab"? The code above says 3.

But that ambiguity doesn't arise for targets - like "TIME_DATA" - where no prefix is equal to a suffix.  It could arise for, e.g., "ATIME_DATA" (with "A" both a suffix and prefix): does that appear once or twice in "ATIME_DATATIME_DATA"? The code above can say "twice" if it's split across chunks like, e.g., "...ATIME_DATATI" and "ME_DATA...".

If you care about that, it could be addressed by doing brief searches to ensure that a match in the pasted-together segment doesn't overlap with a match near the end of the left chunk or near the start of the right chunk.

Comment: so this method is actually the fastest here. I don;t know why. I would like to use it but I need to understand what is going on. I do not understand what this syntax:  "overlap = last[-windowsize :] + memcap[: windowsize]" means and I also I don't understand the rest of the logic below it. But I dont know what type of wizardry you did. Whatever it is, it is the fastest method so far. Even faster than the memory map example